# O que significa "I" em R?

Tags: r

Eu tenho este vetor:

```
df_1 <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = I(list(NULL, NULL, "A")))
```

Que devolve

```
df_1

#  x y
#1 1  
#2 2  
#3 3 A
```

Neste exemplo, ele me permite criar um `data.frame` com um vetor com valores `NULL`.

O que significa `I` em `R` e quando utilizá-lo?

Comment: Sempre tomei `I` como um "atalho" para "identidade". Identidade é a função de X que retorna X.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Da ajuda para `I` (tradução minha):

> Altera a classe de um objeto para indicar que ele deve ser tratado "como é".

Em algumas situações, R trata um objeto como pertencente a uma classe diferente ao avaliar uma expressão. Isso é feito por conveniência, para tornar a sintaxe mais compacta em usos comuns. Nos casos em que se deseja contornar esse comportamento, a função `I` indica para avaliar o objeto como pertencente à sua classe original.

### Fórmulas

Em R, operadores aritméticos pertencem à classe `function`. Mas em fórmulas são usados para especificar facilmente relações entre variáveis. `I` nesse caso mantém a avaliação como operador aritmético. Assim

```
formula(y ~ I(a + b))
```

é o mesmo que:

```
c <- a + b
formula(y ~ c)
```

[Rui Barradas ilustrou bem esse caso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/551093/117168), então não vou me estender.

### data.frames

Por conveniência, algumas classes são convertidas automaticamente ao gerar data.frames. Por exemplo, colunas de matrizes e elementos de listas são convertidos para vetores:

```
v <- letters[1:3]
m <- matrix(1:9, 3)
l <- list(1, 2, 3)

df1 <- data.frame(v, m, l)

str(df1)
#> 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  7 variables:
#>  $ v   : chr  "a" "b" "c"
#>  $ X1  : int  1 2 3
#>  $ X2  : int  4 5 6
#>  $ X3  : int  7 8 9
#>  $ X1.1: num  1 1 1
#>  $ X2.1: num  2 2 2
#>  $ X3.1: num  3 3 3
```

Para manter a estrutura de matriz e lista, usa-se `I`:

```
df2 <- data.frame(v, I(m), I(l))

str(df2)
#> 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ v: chr  "a" "b" "c"
#>  $ m: 'AsIs' int [1:3, 1:3] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
#>  $ l:List of 3
#>   ..$ : num 1
#>   ..$ : num 2
#>   ..$ : num 3
#>   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "AsIs"

df2$m
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    4    7
#> [2,]    2    5    8
#> [3,]    3    6    9
```

**OBS:** O comportamento padrão de `data.frame` para diferentes classes varia com a versão do R.

### NULL

Em R, `NULL` não é um valor, mas uma classe especial de objeto (diferente de `NA`, que é uma constante que indica valor ausente):

```
a <- 1
b <- NULL
c <- NA

c(a, b, c)
#> [1]  1 NA
```

No exemplo que postou, não foi criado um *data.frame* contendo um vetor com valores `NULL`. Com o uso de `I`, criou um data.frame contendo uma lista com objetos da classe `NULL`:

```
df3 <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = I(list(NULL, NULL, 1:4)))

str(df3)
#> 'data.frame':    3 obs. of  2 variables:
#>  $ x: int  1 2 3
#>  $ y:List of 3
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>   ..$ : NULL
#>   ..$ : int  1 2 3 4
#>   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "AsIs"
```

Answer (score 5):

A função `I()` tem dois significados.

Na criação de data.frames, de `help("I")`:

> Details
> Function I has two main uses.
> In function data.frame. Protecting an object by enclosing it in I() in a call to data.frame inhibits the conversion of character vectors to factors and the dropping of names, and ensures that matrices are inserted as single columns. I can also be used to protect objects which are to be added to a data frame, or converted to a data frame via as.data.frame.

Tradução Google

> Detalhes
> A função I tem dois usos principais.
> Na função data.frame. Proteger um objeto colocando-o em I() em uma chamada para data.frame inibe a conversão de vetores de caracteres em fatores e a eliminação de nomes e garante que as matrizes sejam inseridas como colunas únicas. I também pode ser usado para proteger objetos que devem ser adicionados a um quadro de dados ou convertidos em um quadro de dados via as.data.frame.

Isto significa que o argumento de `I` é passado tal e qual está, os `NULL` continuam `NULL`.

---

O outro significado é a utilização em fórmulas. Protege os operadores aritméticos, que são interpretados tal como a fórmula está escrita e não são expandidos pelas regras normais.
Um exemplo permite explicar melhor. A operação aritmética `*` numa fórmula expande para os efeitos pricipais e os efeitos de segundo grau, as interações. Com `I` continua uma multiplicação. O mesmo acontece com a exponenciação a um expoente inteiro, `^`.

**No primeiro caso** a multiplicação `cyl*gear` expande para `cyl + gear + cyl:gear`.

```r
fit <- lm(hp ~ cyl*gear, mtcars)
attr(terms(fit), "term.labels")
#> [1] "cyl"      "gear"     "cyl:gear"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**No segundo caso** o regressor só tem um termo linear. A interação de `cyl` consigo próprio é só `cyl`.
Ou seja, `cyl*cyl == cyl + cyl + cyl:cyl == cyl`.

```r
fit <- lm(hp ~ cyl*cyl, mtcars)
attr(terms(fit), "term.labels")
#> [1] "cyl"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**No terceiro caso** a multiplicação está protegida e o regressor é quadrático.

```r
fit <- lm(hp ~ I(cyl*cyl), mtcars)
attr(terms(fit), "term.labels")
#> [1] "I(cyl * cyl)"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>